# Lambda contains comma

Tags: lambda

I need to see if a value of a property contains a comma and I'm not having any luck.  I've tried contains and indexOf, both of which fail.

> `product_list.Where(a => a.GetValue<string>(s.Name).IndexOf(',') > -1)`

Please overlook the a.GetValue.  It's sitefinity stuff, but it's legit.

Comment: Also, it cannot be linq.  This is in a recursive function, so the product_list is assigned to itself.  I'm 'daisy-chaining' { for lack of a better word } these results together.

Comment: Can you tag this as C# and then also post your actual code with some sample inputs/outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling .ToList() before the Where clause as sometimes the OpenAccess cannot filter these properties on the server.